# How to correctly find domain of this irrational equality?

Tags: inequality, irrational-numbers

(Not sure if "domain" is a right term, but it seems to be closest to Russian term "Область допустимых значений".)

It seems like my previous post lacked details and caused confusion, so there is more detailed question.

I have equation $$\sqrt{4X+2\sqrt{3X^2+4}}=X+2$$

It has three solutions, namely $$
X_1=2;X_2=-2;X_3=0
$$

I was able to find all three solutions. I threw away $$X_3=0$$ because it was outside the domain (in other words, the original equation would just stop make sense or would be false with X=0). But it turned out that X=0 is a valid solution.

Here is story about how I got my domain wrong, if you are interested. Feel free to skip it.
In order to find the domain I tried to solve $$4X+2\sqrt{3X^2+4}\geq0$$

After some manipulations I got $$X\geq-0.5\sqrt{ 3X^2+4 }$$

Then things gone wrong. Here I give my actions step by step:

$$X^2\geq0.25(3X^2+4) $$ 
$$X^2\geq0.75X^2+1 $$ 
$$0.25X^2\geq1 $$
$$X^2\geq4 $$
$$X^2-4\geq0 $$
$$(X+2)(X-2)\geq0 $$
[image]
$$X\in(-∞, -2]\cup[2, ∞)$$

As you can see, X can't be equal to zero. But in fact, it can because the true domain should be $$X\in[-2, ∞)$$.

Here is story of my wrong path to find the domain. **How to correctly find domain of this irrational equality? What is the right way?**

Comment: Why would the original equation stop making sense if $X=0$?

Comment: @pureundergrad Because it how domain (AKA "ОДЗ", "Область допустимых значений") works. For example, in "1/X=4" X can't be equal to zero. But it DOES make sense when X=0 in my case because I got my domain wrong.

Comment: Да, ты неправильно вычислил ОДЗ, посмотри на мой ответ

Comment: I know that I calculated domain (ОДЗ) incorrectly, but what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noted, the step $X^2\geq0.25(3X^2+4)$ is incorrect, since $x\geq y\implies x^2\geq y^2$ holds only for $x,y\geq 0$.

What you need to do is case analysis: first look at the inequality $X\geq-0.5\sqrt{ 3X^2+4 }$ for $X\geq 0$. This always holds, since the right hand side is negative, so it's correct if $X\in [0,\infty)$

Now we look at $X<0$. Since both sides are negative and $x\geq y\implies x^2\leq y^2$ for $x,y<0$, we obtain $X^2\leq 0.25(3X^2+4)$ if $X<0$. This implies $(X+2)(X-2)\leq0$, or $X\in[-2,2]$ if $X<0$, so $X\in[-2,0)$.

So the ОДЗ is $[-2,\infty)$.

Comment: "Now we look at X<0" Why X<0, instead of $$X\leq0$$?

Comment: Yes, when X<0 we will get $$X\in[-2;2]$$. But if we take into account that X<0, then it will mean that $$X\in[-2;0)$$. And finally, we will get $$X\in[-2;0)\cup[2;\infty)$$ instead of $$X∈[−2;∞)$$

Comment: @user161005 "Why $X<0$, instead of $X\leq 0$." Because a real number $X$ is either $\geq 0$ or $<0$, so the case $X=0$ is already covered in the case $X\geq 0$. Checking $X\leq0$ would still be correct, but it's superfluous, because then you're checking $X=0$ twice.

Comment: @user161005 "And finally, we will get $X\in [-2;0)\cup[2;\infty)$ instead of $X\in [-2;\infty)$" No. The case $X\geq 0$ holds for all $X\geq 0$, so we have interval $[0,\infty)$, not $[2,\infty)$. Together with interval $[-2;0)$ this yields $[-2;0)\cup[0;\infty)=[-2;\infty)$. You can fact check your own statement by seeing that the inequality does hold when $X=1$, so $1$ should be part of your interval.

Comment: @user161005 Anyway, your second comment is based on the mistake of the other answer: I did not make that mistake and clearly argued why the inequality holds for $X\in [0,\infty)$ in the case $X\geq 0$. Do you have any more questions/objections/mysteries I need to answer?

Comment: "clearly argued ..." Not clear for me, I'm afraid. Could you please explain why $$X\in [0,\infty)$$?

Comment: @user161005 Alrighty. We consider the case $X\geq 0$, which means that for any (not strict) negative number $Y$ (meaning $Y\leq 0$), we have $X\geq Y$, since $Y\leq 0\leq X$. We know that $\sqrt{ 3X^2+4 }\geq 0$ (this square root yields a non-negative value), so $-0.5\sqrt{ 3X^2+4 }\leq 0$. But this is exactly such a (not strictly) negative number, so we have that $X\geq-0.5\sqrt{ 3X^2+4 }$ is indeed true (for all $X\geq 0$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78373/discussion-between-user161005-and-the-phenotype).

Answer (score 1):

Since the equation has taken the positive sign for the radical you must have first
$$x+2\ge 0\iff x=-2+\epsilon\quad \text {where } \epsilon\ge 0$$
Take now $x=-2+\epsilon$ and verify if this value satisfies $LHS$. You have

$$\sqrt{-8+8\epsilon+8\sqrt{1+\frac{3\epsilon^2-12\epsilon}{16}}}$$ Now make $\epsilon\to 0^+$ and you get $LHS\ge 0$ what agrees with $RHS$.

Thus the domain is $[-2,\infty)$

Comment: +1 for getting rid of inequalities. What I don't get is how one justifies that $-8+8\epsilon+8\sqrt{1+\frac{3\epsilon^2-12\epsilon}{16}}\geq 0$ is true only for $\epsilon\geq 0$. Does it have something to do with it might be increasing?

Comment: @Piquito Why do you use epsilons??

Comment: Because always we need $x\gt -2$ and it is standard using $\epsilon \gt 0$

Comment: @The Phenotype: The true fact used is that $\sqrt{3x^2+4}\ge 1$ so we have  $4x+2\ge 0\iff x\ge-2$ which agree with the $RHS$. What I wanted to use is $\epsilon\to 0$ because $\epsilon\gt 0$ is not enough indeed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I assume your teachers DO NOT require you to solve the equation over the complex numbers (is it right?). Than let's observe possible limitations, which could make the domain of this equality smaller than $(-\infty;+\infty$). There are three such limitations in your equality:

1. $3x^2+4$ should be $\geq0$ (which is true for ($-\infty;+\infty$))
2. LHS is a square root which is $\geq0$, so RHS should also be $\geq0$ (which is true for $[-2;+\infty$))
3. $4x+2\sqrt{3x^2+4}$ should be $\geq0$, which leads to $2\sqrt{3x^2+4} \geq-4x$. It expands in two ways ($-4x\lt0$ (a) and $-4x\geq0$ (b)):

3a) for $x\gt0$ the solution is any valid LHS root (and we already know it is so for $x$ in ($-\infty;+\infty$)) and the common part of the two is $(0;+\infty)$
3b) for $x\leq0$ we square both sides and solve it via $x^2\leq4$ to $[-2;2]$ and the answer for 3b is $[-2;0]$

, so for 3a & 3b in conjunction the domain is $[-2;+\infty)$.

Composing the three big points above we have the domain equal to $[-2;+\infty)$.